# ruby self in an instance methods in a module

Tags: ruby, module, self

```
 class Player
    include Playable

    attr_reader :points
    attr_accessor :health, :name

    def initialize(name, health=100, points=0)
        @name                       = name.capitalize
        @health                     = health
        @found_treasures    = Hash.new(0)
        @points                     = points
    end
  end

module Playable

    def blam  
        self.health -= 10
        puts "#{name} just got blammed yo."
    end

    def w00t
        self.health += 15
        puts "\n#{name} just got w00ted."
    end

    def score
        self.health + points
    end

    def strong?
        health > 100
    end


end
```

So in the above code, I understand that in order to set the attribute health, it needs to 1) be an accessor method in the class that I am including the module in and 2) it needs self in the module.

In this case, what does self refer to? Since the methods in the module are instance methods, they need to be called on an object and so self refers to an instance of the Player class right? If that's correct, then self.health refers to an attr_accessor method and this code makes sense. Without the word "self", it'd be a local variable assignment correct? What is this?

Comment: No, `health` is as much a call to the accessor as `self.health` is. `self.health` is more explicit and readable, though.

Answer (score -1):

[`attr_accessor`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Module.html#method-i-attr_accessor) is simply a `Module`’s method. According to documentation, it (*virtually*: credits to @JörgWMittag) creates an instance variable and both getter method `health` and setter method `health=` (whether you want to create the getter/setter only use `attr_reader` and `attr_writer` respectively.)

When Ruby interpreter finds a new name, it tries to resolve it before creating *new local variable* with this name. As soon as the getter is defined, it is used.

Until you have getter for `health` (defined explicitely, or with a help of `attr_getter`/`attr_accesor`,) this code will create the local variable with that name.

Hope it hepls.

Comment: This is wrong. `attr_accessor` doesn't create an instance variable. Assigning to an instance variable creates an instance variable. How *could* `attr_accessor` even create an instance variable when it is executed at class definition time, before any instance is ever created? Also, local variables shadow methods, not the other way around. It doesn't matter whether you have a getter or not.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I corrected the wording about instance variable, thanks. I never said that methods shadow local variables: “finds a **new** name, it tries to resolve it before creating new local variable.”